# Dart: Float32Array not loaded

Tags: dart

While trying to run some three.dart example codes, I get the following exception:

```
Exception: 'package:three/src/core/Matrix4.dart': Error: line 25 pos 24: type 'Float32Array' >is not loaded
    : elements = new Float32Array(16) {
                              ^
malformed type used.
Breaking on exception: 'package:three/src/core/Matrix4.dart': Error: line 25 pos 24: type 'Float32Array' is not loaded
```

I'm Running the code from Fedora 18 64.

> Btw, I have Dart M4.

<strike>Did I miss the installation of some Dart package?
Did I miss the installation of some Fedora 32 package?</strike>

It seems to be a problem with three.dart, it's not ready to support Dart M4. Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably running an outdated version of the three.dart benchmark. Float32Array has been renamed to Float32List and now lives in dart:typed_data.

Comment: Florian, I installed three.dart using the DartEditor 'Pub Install' tool. Doesn't it has the latest version? Should I try to push the code from the three.dart repository?

Comment: Mistake: Above, I should have typed *pull* instead of *push*.

Comment: The pub package seems to have the latest version. It looks like three.dart hasn't been updated yet.